# Windows 10 - External Hard Drives & Docks losing USB connection - what to restart?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I've got a dozen drives hooked up to my Win10 machine by means of docks and (powered) USB hubs.

After a few hours, several of the drives dismount and refuse to remount. The drives are fine, because the disconnects happen randomly with different drives.

Rebooting the whole computer solves the problem for a few hours, but I'm thinking there is a USB service or driver I can reboot which would accomplish the same thing without forcing the whole system to reboot.

Is there? Where?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using powered USB hubs?  It sounds like you are going over the max amps required and the devices are shutting down.

Comment: it is a powered hub, and when it happens I do turn off drives. But the USB ports never 'come on' again until I reboot. That is my main problem.